# using caret and glmnet for variable selection

Tags: r, cox-model, caret, glmnet

I am using the `caret` and `glmnet` package for variable selection. I only want to find the best model and the coefficients and use them for a different model. Please help me understand the differences between caret and glmnet.
Here's an example:

using state data:

```
data(state)
statedata <- data.frame(state.x77,row.names=state.abb,check.names=T)
statedata <- scale(statedata)
```

in caret:

```
library(caret)
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  repeats = 5)

lassoFit1 <- train(Life.Exp ~ . , data = statedata,
             method = "glmnet",
             trControl = fitControl)
```

I get `alpha=1` and `lambda=0.1` as best values.
But how do I get the final best model?
I tried

```
coef(lassoFit1$finalModel)
```

but I get a whole list of models.

```
coef(lassoFit1$bestTune)
coef(lassoFit1$bestTune$.lambda)
```

both return `NULL`.

Here's how I do it in glmnet:

```
library(glmnet)
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x=statedata[,c(1:3,5,6,7,8)],y=statedata[,4])
```

When I type

```
coef(cvfit, s="lambda.min")
```

I get the coefficients. Is this the best model?
It looks like glmnet does test more lambdas in the cross validation, is that true?
Does caret or glmnet lead to a better model?

How do I manage to extract the best final model from caret and glmnet and plug it in a cox hazard model for example?

thanks

Comment: you may want to try `predictors(lassoFit1)`, which lists predictors used in the final model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the lambdas and your best lambda obtained from caret, you will see that it is not present in the model:

```
lassoFit1$bestTune$lambda
[1] 0.01545996
lassoFit1$bestTune$lambda %in% lassoFit1$finalModel$lambda
[1] FALSE
```

If you do:

```
coef(lassoFit1$finalModel,lassoFit1$bestTune$lambda)
8 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1
(Intercept) -4.532659e-15
Population   1.493984e-01
Income       .           
Illiteracy   .           
Murder      -7.929823e-01
HS.Grad      2.669362e-01
Frost       -1.979238e-01
Area         .
```

It will give you the values from the lambda it tested, that is closest to your best tune lambda. You can of course re-fit the model again with your specified lambda and alpha:

```
fit = glmnet(x=statedata[,c(1:3,5,6,7,8)],y=statedata[,4],
lambda=lassoFit1$bestTune$lambda,alpah=lassoFit1$bestTune$alpha)
> fit$beta
7 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                   s0
Population  0.1493747
Income      .        
Illiteracy  .        
Murder     -0.7929223
HS.Grad     0.2669745
Frost      -0.1979134
Area        .
```

Which you can see is close enough to the first approximation.

To answer your other questions:

> I get the coefficients. Is this the best model?

You did `coef(cvfit, s="lambda.min")` which is the lambda with the least error. If you read the glmnet paper, they go with Breimen's 1SE rule (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/why-is-lambda-within-one-standard-error-from-the-minimum-is-a-recommended-valu) for a complete view), as it calls uses a less complicated model. You might want to consider using `coef(cvfit, s="lambda.1se")`.

> does test more lambdas in the cross validation, is that true? Does
>   caret or glmnet lead to a better model?It looks like glmnet

by default `cv.glmnet` test a defined number of lambdas, in this example it is 67 but you can specify more by passing `lambda=<your set of lambda to test>`. You should get similar values using `caret` or `cv.glmnet`, but note that you cannot vary alpha with `cv.glmnet()`

> How do I manage to extrage the best final model from caret and glmnet
>   and plug it in a cox hazard model for example?

I guess you want to take the non-zero coefficients. and you can do this by

```
#exclude intercept
res = coef(cvfit, s="lambda.1se")[-1,]
names(res)[which(res!=0)]
[1] "Murder"  "HS.Grad"
```