# How exactly does the glmnet in R determine the penalty in ridge regression?

Tags: r, regularization, ridge-regression, glmnet

in R, once I call https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.1-2/topics/cv.glmnet with alpha = 0, I will magically get a set of coefficients from ridge regression, without having to specify anything about the penalty coefficient.

How does glmnet determine the penalty for ridge regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cv.glmnet function uses [k-fold cross-validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) to estimate an optimal penalty term. The default for this software is to use 10 folds. So, the software fits many ridge regressions on a grid of different penalty values and then chooses the value of the penalty parameter that minimizes estimated out-of-sample prediction error, using cross-validation to estimate the out-of-sample prediction error for each choice of the parameter value.

Comment: Is there something going on with `1se`, or is that a different package?

Comment: The 1se choice of lambda can be calculated in the same package. It is a heuristic that uses a slightly different criterion to choose the "best" lambda, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/why-is-lambda-within-one-standard-error-from-the-minimum-is-a-recommended-valu