# Which standard error of out-of-sample prediction errors is used to select the model one standard error from the minimum?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, elastic-net

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625792/what-is-the-standard-error-of-average-cross-validation-error-in-elastic-net-or-l) I established that the standard error of cross-validation prediction error is the standard deviation of prediction error across folds divided by the square root of the number of folds. Hence in a lasso regression with 100 candidate values of lambda there will be 100 standard error of prediction errors.

This brings me to my next question. There is a convention (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/why-is-lambda-within-one-standard-error-from-the-minimum-is-a-recommended-valu) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80268/empirical-justification-for-the-one-standard-error-rule-when-using-cross-validat)) that one should report the results of the simplest model within one standard error of the model with the minimum out-of-sample prediction error. As I mentioned I established that with 100 candidate values of lambda there are 100 standard errors. So my question is **which standard error do we use to make this judgement?**

The figure below plots average out-of-sample prediction error against 100 candidate lambda regularisation parameters in a cross-validation procedure I ran. The red square is the value of lambda that yields the minimum average cv error (called in the package I am using via `fit$lambda.min`) and the green triangle is the value of lambda for the simplest model one se from the minimum (called via `fit$lambda.1se`).

But there are 100 standard errors, one for each model. So **which se is used to select the 1se model?** The se for the minimum cv error model?

[image]