# When I use the Pipeline from Scikit, am I applying a nested cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the image that I am attaching says that a held-out set is needed for feature selection. I know that for feature selection a nested cross-validation is needed. So if I apply "pipeline" I do not need to create an outer cross-validation and neither an inner one. Am I right?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cross_val_score()` function applies Cross Validation to obtain an unbiased measure of the accuracy of a classifier (or pipeline in sklearn).

In the example you provided, the second block of code performs a 3-fold cross validation. The whole dataset $X$ is randomly divided into 3 non-overlaping subsets $X_1, X_2, X_3$. Then, the following experiments are automatically performed:

1. Train a StandarScaler on $X_1,X_2$ and use it to transform $X_1, X_2, X_3$. Train a SVM on the scaled versions of $X_1,X_2$, test on the scaled version of $X_3$.
2. Train a StandarScaler on $X_1,X_3$ and use it to transform $X_1, X_2, X_3$. Train a SVM on the scaled versions of $X_1,X_3$, test on the scaled version of $X_2$.
3. Train a StandarScaler on $X_2,X_3$ and use it to transform $X_1, X_2, X_3$. Train a SVM on the scaled versions of $X_2,X_3$, test on the scaled version of $X_1$.

The accuracies obtained on these three experiments can be averaged to obtain an unbiased estimate of the generalization accuracy of your pipeline: `StandardScaller() + SVC(C=1)`. However, if you started playing with the hyperparameters of your classifier (e.g. trying different C values) the best accuracy obtained would not be an unbiased estimate.

Nested CV is necesary if you want to perform hyperparametrer/model selection (inner loop) and obtain an unbiased estimate of the accuracy of your method (outer loop).

These topics have been already discused in more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178174/when-is-nested-cross-validation-really-needed-and-can-make-a-practical-differenc) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224287/cross-validation-misuse-reporting-performance-for-the-best-hyperparameter-value). In short: "the outer loop is to assess the performance of the model, and the inner loop is to select the best model".

Comment: Can you help me answer this other question: [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250066/how-to-scale-data-without-introducing-bias-in-sklearn]