# Understanding ACF and PACF plots for model selection for AR(1) vs AR(2)

Tags: time-series, residuals, acf-pacf

Good afternoon all,

I've got a model that models a time series and I am trying to decide which how the residuals are correlated. The first model, called $m1$ is models $AR(1)$ residuals and the second model models $AR(2)$ residuals called $m2$. I'm looking at the residual plots, ACF/PACF plots and also the AIC/BIC values of the two models to decide if $m1$ or $m2$ would a better model for the residuals. However upon closer inspection I cannot determine which one would be best as they are both very similar in the analysis and I lean more towards the AR(1) model since it is simpler. Are my assessments correct on this and am I understanding the ACF/PACF plots correctly?

**ACF/PACF of $m1$ and $m2$**

Analysis: There appears to be slightly less variability in the ACF/PACF for the $m1$ model. I'm also having some issues fully understanding these ACF/PACF plots.
[image]

**Plots of the residuals of $m1$ and $m2$**

Analysis: No apparent difference in the residuals between the $m1$ and $m2$ as they are almost identical.
[image]

**AIC/BIC values**

m1: -286.812/-274.2221

m2: -287.7302/-271.9928

Analysis: AIC slightly favors $m2$ and BIC slightly favors $m1$.

Thank you for the time.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Yes I did forget the minus sign and the interpretation's also been fixed. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you have reached the point where the models are effectively the same. I would also assume that any forecasts are essentially indistinguishable. In such a case, I would always go with the simpler model, compare the ["one standard error" rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80268/1352).

Also, I would usually prefer using information criteria over reading entrails, sorry, I meant ACF/PACF plots: [Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352). In the present case, the two criteria give conflicting advice. Another reason not to stress too much about this.

Comment: Thank you for the links and the references. I do agree that the simpler model is the best choice since they are almost identical. This is the last portion of a new technique that is in development and a lot of the results always point to either an AR(1) or AR(2) however the differences are always so little that AR(1) is always chosen. I was just trying to see if there was a better approach to taken in the model selection process as processes such as MLE, REML or any form of likelihood cannot be used since the modelling technique for the main model is non-parametric. Thank you for the input.

Comment: As a forecaster, I would say that one possibility would be to use a holdout sample and see which model yields better forecasts. But with your models being so similar, I would assume changing the holdout length by a few periods might again change which model performs best.

Comment: Thank you, I will take that into consideration. I may also look into seeing if using the MAPE provides a bit of a stronger argument for the AR(1) or AR(2) model and see if that stays more consistent.

Comment: I am very much not a fan of the MAPE. It elicits a different functional than the expectation (which ARIMA tries to predict). Simply said, minimizing the MAPE is not what your ARIMA is trying to do. I would very much recommend you use the MSE instead, which is aligned with ARIMA in eliciting the expectation. See [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) and references therein.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the references.