# Cross validation misunderstanding

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, predictive-models

I have some questions about the use of CV in machine learning,
I created a post some days ago and I have been given a link to a previous post (very interesting). I also read this post (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/12/the-cross-validation-train-predict-misunderstanding/) about the misconception of cross validation and train-predict.
If I understand correctly :

1. Cross validation cannot allow me to choose a model over another
2. Cross validation cannot allow me also to choose a set of hyperparameters among all the folds which seems very logic (bias induced+++)

So : I can only have an estimation of the average metric I chose on independent set with a very useful variance (the lower the better).
I saw also some posts with explanations about the one standard error rule ([Empirical justification for the one standard error rule when using cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80268/empirical-justification-for-the-one-standard-error-rule-when-using-cross-validat)) but it confuses me...

In definitive, I can see with the CV if there is a stability between the inner and outer loop, and with the mean and sd of the performance (outer loop) I can choose a model performing better than others ? and in a case of equality, use the one standard error rule (for example) ?

I feel so stupid because there is 3 tons of posts about this and I still don't understand...